# How to make the starting and ending for some lines to be different in java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am trying to create this shape:

```
<>()<>()<>
()<>()<>()
<>()<>()<>
()<>()<>()
<>()<>()<>
```

If I use any even number for n everything is good But when I use an odd number for n the starting for all lines are same.

This is my code:

```
int n = 5, line = 1, colomn = 1;

    for (int i=0; i< (n*n); i++){

        if ((line % 2) == 0){
            System.out.print((((i%2) == 0) ? "()" : "<>"));
        }else{
            System.out.print((((i%2) == 1) ? "()" : "<>"));
        }

        if (colomn == n){
            colomn = 1;
            line++;
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            colomn++;
        }
    }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: You can just use `System.out.print((line + column) % 2 == 0 ? "()" : "<>");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use colomn instead of i:

```
    if ((line % 2) == 0){
        System.out.print((((colomn%2) == 0) ? "()" : "<>"));
    }else{
        System.out.print((((colomn%2) == 1) ? "()" : "<>"));
    }
```

Comment: @user3197337 the code can be further simplyfied. See my answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

With n=3 first line has i=0,1,2 second i=3,4,5 third i=6,7,8. i=0 and i=3 in the same row have a different pattern, but as they are in different lines the second condition flips this pattern.

Either switch `i` with `colomn` inside print or use

```
    int n = 5;

    for (int line = 0; line < n; line++) {

        for (int column=0; column < n; column++){

            if ((line + column) % 2 == 0){
                System.out.print("<>");
            }else{
                System.out.print("()");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution:

```
   int n = 5, line = 0;
   for (int i = 1; i <= n*n; i++){
       String str;

       if (n % 2 == 0 && line % 2 == 0)
           str = i % 2 == 0 ? "<>" : "()";
       else
           str = i % 2 == 0 ? "()" : "<>";

       System.out.print(str);

       if (i % n == 0) {
           System.out.println();
           line++;
       }    
   }
```